# How to make deterministic random number generator?

Tags: c, random, openssl, cryptography

I was doing some experiments with cryptography, and now I am trying to make a deterministic random number generator (DRBG). It should be a counter mode based deterministic random bit generator using AES-128 block cipher specified in
NIST SP 800-90.

I have the source code of OpenSSL. In OpenSSL, there are two functions `RAND_bytes()` and `RAND_pseudo_bytes()` to be used as random number generator.

How to configure this OpenSSL random number generator as counter mode based DRBG using AES-128 block cipher?

Comment: If this is for play, it isn't hard to make a DRBG (even one that is NIST compliant).  If you want to work more productively then you can borrow one of the [DRBG](http://github.com/TomMD/DRBG) implementations out there.  If this is for production then ask yourself why do you care if your RNG is deterministic in the first place?

Comment: it has to be deterministic, and it is for productive purpose

Comment: Does it matter if it's open source (GPL)?  Do you need backtracking resistance?  Do you need any degree of prediction resistance?

Comment: You could follow the instructions at [this question's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437177/force-openssls-rngs-to-return-a-repeatable-byte-sequence) answer, but just replace the libc `rand()`-based implementation with your AES-based PRNG. If you need specific help with that part, I'd recommend asking a separate question about it and describing what you've managed to do so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making openssl generate deterministic key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22759465/608639)

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to specify a random seed:

http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RAND_add.html#

It seems that you can also save and reload a sequence generated:

http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/rand.html

Comment: can you tell me which is the default algorithm it takes for number generation. I want aes-128 block ciphering , how to configure that ?

Comment: @jithin I do not have direct experience with that library, sorry. What I tried to answer was how to make it **deterministic**. Maybe you should ask another question.

Comment: This will not work. OpenSSL mixes in additional random state, so the sequence will not repeat based on a seed.

Comment: @jww I think this is very interesting, why don't you put it down with more details in a separate answer?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41284412/3075942) is the explanation why this doesn't work.