# Making OpenSSL generate deterministic key

Tags: random, openssl

I'm trying to make openssl generate deterministic private and public RSA key-pair. The idea is that I fill my seedbuf with a HASH of some device dependent data, and use that as a seed. But seeding the RAND does not seem to work, the keys are still randomized.

For various reasons I don't want to just generate the key once, and then store it, I only want the private key to exist in memory.

```
RAND_seed(seedbuf, sizeof(seedbuf));

bne = BN_new();
if (1 != BN_set_word(bne,e)) {
    goto free_stuff;
}

keypair = RSA_new();
if(1 != RSA_generate_key_ex(keypair, KEY_LENGTH, bne, NULL)) {
    goto free_stuff;
}
```

So basically I want the "RSA_generate_key_ex" function to return same key-pair, each time it is seeded with same input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Making openssl generate deterministic key...

I don't believe you can do it out of the box. By default, OpenSSL uses `md_rand`, and that auto seeds itself. Calling `rand_seed` internally calls `rand_add`, which adds to the state (rather than discarding/replacing state). You can find the source for `md_rand` in `crypto/rand/md_rand.c`.

If you build with `FIPS` enabled, then there are deterministic random bit generators from NIST's SP 800-90. However, I seem to recall they operate in similar fashion to `md_rand`. That is, you can add to internal state, but you can't really control it. You can find the source in `crypto/rand/rand_lib.c`.

I think you have one option. You can create you own `my_rand`. Base it on a block cipher or hash. On startup, seed it with device dependent data, and then return the deterministic bytes.

Now, to get functions like `RSA_generate_key_ex` to use your PRNG, you have to package it in an OpenSSL `ENGINE`. Richard Levitte of OpenSSL has a nice two-series blog at [Engine Building Lesson 1: A Minimum Useless Engine](https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2015/10/08/engine-building-lesson-1-a-minimum-useless-engine/) and [Engine Building Lesson 2: An Example MD5 Engine](https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2015/11/23/engine-building-lesson-2-an-example-md5-engine/) on the OpenSSL blog.

Once you package it with an engine, you can use it like so. After you set the random method with `ENGINE_METHOD_RAND`, you will be using your algorithm.

```
ENGINE* eng = ENGINE_by_id("my_rand");
unsigned long err = ERR_get_error();

if(NULL == eng) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ENGINE_by_id failed, err = 0x%lx\n", err);
    abort(); /* failed */
}

int rc = ENGINE_init(eng);
err = ERR_get_error();

if(0 == rc) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ENGINE_init failed, err = 0x%lx\n", err);
    abort(); /* failed */
}

rc = ENGINE_set_default(eng, ENGINE_METHOD_RAND);
err = ERR_get_error();

if(0 == rc) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ENGINE_set_default failed, err = 0x%lx\n", err);
    abort(); /* failed */
}
```

If you want to look at a `ENGINE` implementation, take a look at the `rdrand` engine in `crypto/engine/eng_rdrand.c`. There's not much to the engine, and it will be easy to copy/paste. Be sure to add your new engine to the `Makefile` in `crypto/engine/Makefile`.

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for a way to generate deterministic keys not necessarily using OpenSSL, [GnuTLS](https://www.gnutls.org/manual/html_node/certtool-Invocation.html) may be able to help:

```
certtool --generate-privkey --outfile privkey.pem --key-type=rsa --sec-param=high --seed=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Using `--seed`, at least in the current version, implies using `--provable` algorithm generation (FIPS PUB186-4).

The generated `privkey.pem` will be in RSA-PSS format, you can use the following command to convert it to raw RSA format:

```
certtool --to-rsa --load-privkey privkey.pem --outfile privkey.key
```

Then from a key in either format you can generate a self-signed certificate, if needed:

```
certtool --generate-self-signed --load-privkey privkey.key --outfile signed.crt --template cert.cfg
```

If you'd like to make this step deterministic too or avoid answering the questions each time you run the command, add `--template cert.cfg` parameter to the last command. The minimum content of `cert.cfg` file to make the generation deterministic would be:

```
serial = 1
activation_date = "2019-01-01 00:00:00 UTC"
expiration_date = "2029-01-01 00:00:00 UTC"
```

Comment: Will it be useful when working with 4 seeds? I can’t find a way to convert two random and two private keys (server & client) into one master key, as the final step of the ssl handshake process. Thanks

Comment: @OriDavid: I don't quite understand your question and what are you trying to achieve. There is no such thing as master key in TLS. Do you need a CA cert?

Comment: I want to implement step 4 of the [IBM overview of the SSL handshake](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q009930_.htm#q009930___q009930_1), though I don't know how to `"compute the secret key"`. Assuming I have the necessary keys, what is the formula?

Comment: @OriDavid: If you need that level of detail, you are better off reading the specification directly ([RFC 8446](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8446) for TLS 1.3, see [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) for previous versions) and probably some TLS library source code. Anyway, TLS implementation details are totally out of scope of this question, so you should ask another one and maybe even on another site like [Crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: On my system, the key is not identical, if the seed has not the expected length. The expected lengths are documented [here](https://github.com/gnutls/gnutls/blob/b665409cbc1a54e0f64b0672d4a7ac43b3f6c9c1/src/certtool.c#L234)