# determinisitic random number generator giving different random number for same seed

Tags: c++, c, random, openssl

I want to use a deterministic random bit generator for my application. I' m using openssl for random number generator apis. Currently I'm using RAND_pseuso_bytes() api for generating pseudo random numbers. And I'm giving seed through RAND_add(). Then if I called the Random generator function two times, I'm getting two different random values at these two calls. If the seed is same, then it should give me the same values, where I have gone wrong ?

The code I have written is

```
int nSize = 8;    /* 64 bit random number is required */ 
int nEntropy = 5; /* 40 bit entropy required */
/* generate random nonce for making seed */
RAND_bytes(cSeed_64, nSize);
RAND_add(cSeed_64, nSize, nEntropy); /* random nonce is cSeed_64, seedin 64 bit with
                                      *  40 bit entropy */
/* calling random byte function to generate random number function 10 times with same seed*/
int j = 10;
while( j--)
{
    RAND_pseudo_bytes(cRandBytes_64, 8);
    printf("generated 64 bit random number \n");
    for(i = 0 ; i < nSize; i++)
        printf("%x ",cRandBytes_64[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: So you're wondering why a random number generator returns random numbers? I don't understand what you're expecting here.  You're generating a new seed with `RAND_bytes()`, then generating a sequence of pseudo-random values with `RAND_pseudo_bytes()`. This is normal use.  What are you trying to accomplish differently?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force openssl's RNGs to return a repeatable byte sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437177/force-openssls-rngs-to-return-a-repeatable-byte-sequence)

Answer (score 1):

But you're NOT calling `RAND_psuedo_bytes()` with the same seed, you're making successive calls to it, which *should* produce different outputs. That's the whole point of a "generator" function--it produces a different value on each call based on internal state.

When you "seed" and random number generator, you fix its internal state, after which it will generate random numbers by evolving that state. For each seed, it will generate a unique and reproducible *sequence* of numbers from repeated calls, but it certainly won't generate the same numbers on each call, that would be pointless.

The line:

```
RAND_bytes(cSeed_64, nSize);
```

creates a random see value based on system entropy. You really should check for errors here, as it may fail if not enough entropy is available.

The line

```
RAND_add(cSeed_64, nSize, nEntropy);
```

DOES NOT seed the PRNG, it *adds* the seed to the existing PRNG state. If you want to set the PRNG state to a fixed value, you have to use `RAND_seed()`.  If you call `RAND_seed()` with a given value, `RAND_pseudo_bytes()` will thereafter generate a given *sequence* of random numbers. If you call `RAND_seed()` again with the same value, it will then repeat the same sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to seed it every time you call it, else it is expected to return a random number every time you call it.

Comment: thanks @Karthik but I tried seeding it everytime before  calling the random generation function... still it is not working...

Answer (score -1):

In your code

```
RAND_bytes(cSeed_64, nSize);
RAND_add(cSeed_64, nSize, nEntropy);
```

You are generating a random number using `RAND_bytes`. You are adding this random number into seed. Since, you are adding randomness to already something random, it should generate random number every time. So, seed is not same everytime since it is random.

To keep the seed same, try `RAND_seed` with a fixed seed to get the expected behaviour.